# Susy One Gem Error Deprication Warning

Tags: css, ruby, rubygems, susy

I am running CodeKit and I get this error when it compiles:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING on line 60, column 11 of /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/susy-2.1.3/sass/susy/language/susyone/_functions.scss:
Unescaped multiline strings are deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Sass.
To include a newline in a string, use "\a" or "\a " as in CSS.
```

that error happens a couple of times in different areas.

And this one:

```
Sass::SyntaxError on line ["280"] of /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.1.0.alpha.3/stylesheets/compass/_support.scss: List index is 2 but list is only 1 item long for `nth'
```

I have updated my gems and I am running Ruby 2.0.0p481.  Any idea what is going on?

Thanks,
Stan

Comment: i get the same issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26653313/issues-with-upgrading-gems

Answer (score 1):

Future versions of SASS won't allow multi-line strings, so you're getting the warning to remove them.

If you have multi-line strings like:

```
$foo: '.class1, .class2, .class3, 
       .class4, .class5, .class6';
```

Add a `\a` character at the end of each line, and close and open each quotation mark, such as:

```
$foo: '.class1, .class2, .class3, \a' 
      '.class4, .class5, .class6';
```