# Issues with upgrading gems

Tags: compass-sass, susy-compass

i've started a project with compass 0.12 and sass 1 and susy 1.0.9.Now i want to resume it and i done an upgrade for gems.So i have now newers versions for compass (1.0.1), sass (3.4.0, 3.2.12)
 ans susy (2.1.3).
So i found a fix to use old syntax for susy 1,

```
@import "susyone";
```

but i still get errors for compass:

```
 (Line 280 of /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/_support.scss: List index is 2 but list is only 1 item long for `nth')
```

This nth is used for an additional buttons styles.So i don't find other ways to fix this.
Can i specify a compass version to use ?

Thanks

Comment: this error come from `@include susy-grid-background;` but now i get an error with compass recipes.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the same issue [documented on github here](https://github.com/ericam/susy/issues/395) and [in Compass here](https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1853). I'm not sure about any work-arounds at this point, besides turning off grid-image output for the time being.